# Relate CTE to main part of query, or is CTE even needed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I've been playing with CHAT GTP to create a query that I need. Together we got:

```
WITH employeeCompensation AS 
     (SELECT hourlyBonus, shiftBonus
      FROM empComp
      WHERE selfmanagerid = 1 AND
            employeeNumber = ER.employeeNumber AND
            effectiveDate >= WS.dateSoS
      FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY)        
SELECT ER.lastName, ER.firstName, ER.employeeNumber, hourlyBonus, shiftBonus
       EC.hourlyBonus, EC.shiftBonus,
       WS.dateSoS, EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM (WS.dateEoS + WS.timeEoS - WS.dateSoS - WS.timeSoS)) / 60 AS shiftDuration, 
       WS.wageType,
       H.holidate 
FROM workSchedules WS 
        INNER JOIN schedXEmp SXE ON SXE.schedId = WS.recId 
        INNER JOIN empRec ER ON ER.selfManagerId = 1 AND 
                   ER.employeeNumber = SXE.employeeNumber 
        LEFT JOIN lkupHolidays H ON (H.holidate = WS.dateSoS AND 
                                     H.deactivatedTs > H.holidate) 
WHERE WS.dateSoS BETWEEN '2020-4-15' AND '2020-10-15' AND 
      WS.deactivatedTs > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AND 
      WS.selfmanagerid = 1 
ORDER BY ER.lastName, ER.firstName, WS.wageType, WS.dateSoS, WS.timeSoS
;
```

of course, this does not work as PostgreSQL doesn't like referencing ER and WS in the CTE. It wants me to move those to an INNER JOIN near the bottom. But doing this would not get the same recordset in my CTE as it wound get the first record of any employee and date, then try to join that one record.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Please explain what you want, share some examples and expected results.

Comment: But your main query isn't even using your CTE, making your intent really ambiguous. Perhaps instead of asking ChatGPT to generate magical SQL for you, you could edit your post to include the prompt you used and some more schema information, then you can get some real assistance from the community tailored to your level of understanding.

Comment: General rule: A CTE is never needed. In some cases, it makes it much easier to write a correct query, in some cases people use it without any reason, in all cases it is possible to write a query without CTE that produces the same result.

Answer (score 0):

> PostgreSQL doesn't like referencing ER and WS in the CTE

You have misinterpreted how CTE works, the query in the CTE must be executable idependently, it can't reference tables that are not included in it's scope. So you'll need to include these joins in the CTE first.

- Is it correct that your CTE should only return 1 row?

```
    SELECT hourlyBonus, shiftBonus
    FROM empComp
    WHERE selfmanagerid = 1 
      AND employeeNumber = ER.employeeNumber 
      AND effectiveDate >= WS.dateSoS
    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

So we need to join in ER and WS so you can use this, but there is not enough information available for me to make this determination for you.

The main query isn't even using your CTE, making the intent really ambiguous. Perhaps instead of asking ChatGPT to generate magical SQL for you, you need to make a new post that has your original query or prompt. SO is not a code writing service, but you can ask specific questions about technique or for us to help you debug queries that you have attempted

Comment: You are all correct that my question was not as clear as could be. I've already been flagged as not being clear enough. At times it becomes hard to decipher between what is clear to me because I've been at it for hours, vs the world who is newly exposed to the problem. Yes, SO is not a code writing service, but an amazing resource. I'll break down my problem into a few SQLs and put everything together with PHP. Thanks all.

Comment: There is probably a simple SQL solution, the problem is that because your query is not formed correctly, I can't tell what you actually want. I better formed question would include schema information, example input data and an example output that matches the input. Also some explanation about the intent. All of these things are missing, but because the query itself doesn't work, we can't easily identify the schema. We're not supposed to post answers to questions in this state, but comments don't really give enough space to give you the feedback you need to get this right.